# Most suitable graph for displaying coordinate data

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have extracted some sets of matrices from a CSV file that comes from recording data (X,Y) every N seconds in a C++ application.

In my C++ application I was tracking two objects and saving the coordinates of both in my CSV file like so:

```
x1, y1, x2, y2    
x1, y1, x2, y2
...
```

I would like to display both objects `(x,y)1`  and `(x,y)2` in the same graph at the same time, but `scatter` does not seem to allow this.

Something like the following would be ideal:

```
scatter(Log1(:,1),Log1(:,2), Log1(:,3),Log1(:,4))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`hold`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html?refresh=true)`on`.

Something like

```
scatter(Log1(:,1),Log1(:,2));
hold on
scatter(Log1(:,3),Log1(:,4));
```